# Rule-based deletions from string list

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a list of strings:

```
lis = {"a","b","c","12","d","q","r","X","s"}
```

I'd like to delete list members starting with "X" moving backwards through the list from "X" until a list member that's a digit character is found, to get:

```
res = {"a","b","c","12","s"}
```

Not sure how to use DeleteCases here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would need something like `DeleteSubsequenceCases`, but it doesn't exist. I would recommend this instead:

```
SequenceReplace[lis, {d_?(StringMatchQ[NumberString]), ___, "X"} :> d]
```

If `X` only appears once, you could also use this:

```
First@SequenceCases[lis, {a___, d_?(StringMatchQ[NumberString]), ___, "X", b___} :> {a, "12", b}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Replace[lis, {a___, b_String?(StringMatchQ[NumberString]), Shortest[c___], "X", d___} :> 
  {a, b, d}]
```

> {"a", "b", "c", "12", "s"}

Answer (score 3):

```
rlis = Reverse[lis];
xpos = First[Flatten[Position[StringMatchQ[rlis, "X"], True]]];
Reverse[Drop[rlis, {xpos, xpos + LengthWhile[rlis[[xpos + 1 ;;]], 
     StringMatchQ[#, NumberString] == False &]}]]
```

> {"a", "b", "c", "12", "s"}

Answer (score 3):

This was a good opportunity to use `Cases` and compare it with other presented techniques.

I have added another entry in `lis2` that is a `NumberString` in order to experiment.

```
lis2 = {"a", "b", "c", "12", "d", "13", "q", "r", "X", "s"}

Cases[Reverse@lis2
   , {
     g___
     , "X"
     , Longest[_String?(FreeQ[NumberString]) ..], 
     s_?(StringMatchQ[NumberString])
     , h___
     } :> {g, s, h}, All] // First // Reverse
```

> {"a", "b", "c", "12", "s"}

The extra layer of `{}` is removed with `First`. This can be avoided by modifying the last line above as follows:

```
... } :> Sequence @@ {g, s, h}, All] // Reverse
```

It also helps to have the the list displayed in reverse order as one is writing the pattern.

Without the `Longest` pattern object:

```
Cases[Reverse@lis2
   , {
     g___
     , "X"
     , _String?(FreeQ[NumberString]) ..
     , s_?(StringMatchQ[NumberString])
     , h___} :> {g, s, h}, All] // First // Reverse
```

> {"a", "b", "c", "12", "d", "13", "s"}

Answer (score 0):

Using `Partition` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
ReplaceAll[
    Last[
        Map[Function[Join @@ If[SameQ[FreeQ[#, "X"], True], #, Nothing]],
            Map[Function @ Partition[lis, {#}], Range @ Length @lis]
        ]
    ],
    {x__, "12", y__} :> {x, 12, "s"}
 ]

(*{"a", "b", "c", 12, "s"}*)
```